# Yii2 check if ActiveRecord Successfully loaded a record

Tags: php, yii2

How to check if data exists in DB and loaded in the ActiveRecord model. For example, in Kohana, there is function `loaded` to check that ORM successfully loaded a record.

```
  class Model_Image extends ORM {
    public function url($width = NULL)
    {
        if( ! $this->loaded()){
            return NULL;
        }
        ...
    }
```

I have got the class named Image it is extended from ActiveRecord. Class Image has url function, inside function url I should check if a data was loaded, or it is the new one?

Is there something similar in Yii2 to check if ActiveRecord successfully loaded a record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `findOne()` (simply `one()`) on ActiveRecord model where condition is not met it returns `null`.

When you use `findAll()` (simply `all()`) on ActiveRecord model where condition is not met it returns empty array.

So all you need to check is if the ActiveRecord is not empty.

Example:

```
$model = MyActiveRecordModel::findOne(1);
if (empty($model)) {
    // DB row not found
} else {
    // DB row found
}
```

Additionally you can check boolean property `isNewRecord` of model:

```
if ($model->isNewRecord) {
    // no previously db data loaded - 
    // new instance of model (new data not saved yet)
}
```

Comment: How to check if the ActiveRecord is not empty inside ActiveRecord model, for example, I have got inside my AR model function URL that supposes to generate url.

Comment: What do you mean? This is totally different question from your first one.

Comment: Example for checking if empty added.

Comment: For example in Kohana you can check if a data loaded inside ORM instance class, `$this->loaded()`. The question is the same. I have got the class named Image it is extended from ActiveRecord. Class Image has url function, inside function url I should check if a data was loaded, or it is the new one?

Comment: Example how Kohana ORM does it, added.

Comment: You can check isNewRecord. Example added.

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

If this is one item:

```
$model = User::findOne(1);
if($model){
 //all good
}else{
 //no data
}
```

If multiple model then

```
$model = User::findAll(1);
```

Always return array, so if array have no elements then **foreach** will don`t run body of cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Check For The existence of data:

```
 <?php $checkForExistenceOfData = Model::find()->exists();
    if($checkForExistenceOfData == true){
       $getModelData = Model::findAll();
    }else{
       echo 'No Data Exists';
   }
 ?>
```